# android 6.0.1 bluetooth list of devices

Tags: android, bluetooth

I tried a bluetooth code to show bluetooth devices and making connection in android and it worked in android 4.4.2 very well. when running the same app in android 6.0.1 (Samsung Note 5) it doesnt show list of devices and only asks for bluetooth only one time. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: could you share your bluetooth related code?

Comment: Are you given run time permission??

Comment: In my code every time the app runs it always asks to turn on bluetooth then list all bluetooth devices. In Android 6.0.1 it only asks to run the bluetooth the first time run and don't show the list of bluetooth devices!